# jQuery e.preventDefault() not Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have few lines of code to create a form and then later in the code I am using AJAX `$.post` through JSON.

My html form scripting code creates a simple form and then by pressing a "enviar (submit) button, it'll print my vars data. I am calling with `$.post` a file called dados.php, as you'll see later in this message.

I am in the impression that by using jQuery `preventDefault()` by clicking in the the "enviar" button nothing would happen but it'll bring to other page showing data from my vars (I am doing `print_r($_POST);` and `var_dump($_POST);` inside my dados.php.

First, I could be wrong to thing that jQuery `preventDefault()` or others (you'll see commented in my code) "prevent" any action after the user/me click on the "enviar"(submit) button; nothing would happen, but still prints my vars data.

Second/lastly, there's something wrong with my code.

Please check the following scripting code for my HTML form and for my dados.php (php code); In advance I really appreciate your help:

***MY HTML FORM/JSON:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="result">texto do cliente</div>​

    <form id ="myform"action="dados.php" method="post">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Nome:</td>            
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="first_name" value="" maxlength="25" />
                </td>            
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Sexo:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="Sexo" value="Masculino" /> Masculino
                    <input type="radio" id="Sexo" value="Feminino" /> Feminino
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td>Profissão:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="dropdown">
                    <option value ="administrador">Administrador</option>
                    <option value ="analista">Analista</option>
                    <option value ="designer">Designer</option>
                    <option value ="gerente">Gerente</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="enviar"/>                    
                </td>
                </tr>
        </table>  

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                /* attach a submit handler to the form */
                $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {

                /* stop form from submitting normally */
                   e.preventDefault(); 
                   //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                   //e.stopPropagation();

            $.post(   
                'dados.php', {firstname: $('#first_name').val(), sexo: $('#sexo').val(),
                             profissão: $('#dropdown').val()}, function(data) {  
                console.log(data);
                //$('#result').html(data)
                //$('#result').html(data.firstname)
                //$('#result').html(data.sexo)
                //$('#result').html(data.profissão)
                }, 'json');
            });           

         </script>        

        <script>

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

***MY DADOS.PHP:***

```
//ECHO $_POST['dropdown'];

print_r($_POST);

var_dump($_POST);
```

Big Thanks.

Marco Lanza

Comment: Is this your actual code?  If so, it doesn't look like you are closing all your function calls correctly.  Right now, you are only closing the click() function, but never the outermost anonymous function.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't close your `$(function(){`.

You need to add another `});` at the end.

Comment: @MarcoLanza -- Glad it worked. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the check to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return false;` to the end of your callback. I usually just set this on the form itself if I'm planning to make an AJAX form: `<form action="someAction" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">`

Also, you should attach to the `submit` event on the `form` rather than the `click` event on the button - remember that if the user presses the Enter key, the form will submit, bypassing the event handler on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
```

Try this:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
```

Comment: @mattytommo Not really, you can submit the form without clicking the button. Also, returning false or preventDefault from the click handler won't stop the form from submitting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will? It's just preventDefault is preferred over return false :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put your jQuery script into HTML header and change `$(function()` to `$(document).ready(function(){`?

Answer (score 0):

`$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {` isn't a submit handler, it's a click handler for the submit button, which probably isn't what you actually need.

Try replacing that line with `$("form#myform").submit(function(e) {` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change to a form submit where you have this:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
```

do this:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, you should just use `<input type="button">` and add the click handler to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting return false; after your $.post call